# Can select list in amp-form trigger a change in a second select list in the form?

Tags: amp-html

Is it possible to have a two select lists and make the second options dependend on the value of the first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the substitutions feature in [amp-list](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-list) which allows variables to be used inside of strings and substituted with the corresponding actual values dependent on user actions.

See the [Substitutions Guide](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-var-substitutions.md) to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. Use on change AMP.setState on the first select input to set the value of the [text] on the option of the second select input. Here is a simplified example:

```
  <form method="GET"
  class="p2"
  action="/"
  target="_top">
    <div class="ampstart-input form-elem">
      <label for="sel1" class="form-label">Select1</label>
        <select name="sel1"
          id="sel1"
          on="change:AMP.setState({jsonData: {key : event.value}})">
          <option value="a">example 1</option>
          <option value="b">example 2</option>
          <option value="c">example 3</option>
          <option value="d">example 4</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="ampstart-input form-elem">
        <label for="sel2" class="form-label">Select2</label>
        <select name="sel2"
          id="sel2">
          <option [text]="jsonData[(jsonData.key + '1')]">a example</option>

        </select>
      </div>
    <amp-state id="jsonData">
      <script type="application/json">
        {"key" : "",
         "a1":"a1 example",
         "a2":"a2 example",
         "b1":"b1 example",
         "b2":"b2 example",
         "c1":"c1 example",
         "c2":"c2 example",
         "d1":"d1 example",
         "d2":"d2 example"}
      </script>
    </amp-state>  
  </form>
```

You will have to work out the logic of the amp-state json to meet your specific needs.